# flex 4.5 AIR Captive Runtime Support: missing option

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I am using Flex4.5.

When creating an AIR application and trying to export it, I **do not have AIR Captive Runtime Support support:**
I just have 3 options:
- signed air package
- signed native installer
- intermediate AIRI package.

My application uses 4.5.1 framework. I saw on adobe videos, there is a 4th export option I actually do not have: what's wrong ?

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT : I previously reported the feature was introduced in the Flex 4.6 framework. It seems it was however introduced in the AIR 3.0 sdk. All you need is to download the AIR sdk and copy it in your Flex sdk folder (or a copy of it if you want to keep your original Flex sdk), overwriting the AIR sdk files. Simple as that.

If you're using Flash Builder, you'll also need it's version to be 4.6 (wich should be compatible with your current Flash Builder 4.5 licence).

Comment: Minor detail: I think it's now for non-**iOS** apps, rather than just for non-**mobile** apps.  I might be wrong, but I don't think you could deploy to Android using Captive Runtime prior to 4.6.

Comment: I looked into this and you're right. I've edited my answer as I also discovered it's related to AIR, not Flex (wich really makes sense when you think about it!)

Comment: Yes, you're right about captive runtime being an AIR SDK feature, but in terms of IDE support it still requires Flash Builder **4.6**, as you had already correctly noted.  Furthermore, the AIR SDK (3.1) is a subset of the Flex 4.6 SDK, so you don't really need to download it separately.  See [Flex 4.6 Release Notes](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/921/cpsid_92118.html).

Comment: Yeah I know that, but you can still use the AIR 3 SDK with the Flex 4.5 framework if you want to